# How to add custom columns to grid items designer in FireMonkey

Tags: delphi, custom-controls, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I have created a custom column `TComboColumn = class(FMX.Grid.TColumn)` for `TGrid`. Currently I have to add this column to grids in the code, but I would like to be able to do this using the `TGrid` items designer, like I can when adding default column types (`TColumn`, `TStringColumn`, `TCheckColumn` etc).

Comment: I hear your pain. I tried various things, chiefly based around registering the column as a component or FMX class and Delphi didn't want to play ball. I can only conclude (sadly), that the columns available are somehow hard coded.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly Tools API doesn't provide support...
Possible decision: to write and register own component editor (from TComponentEditor).
The report of this problem on QC: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=107177

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).